# Google Bigquery create table with no code? syntax

Tags: google-bigquery

I was hoping to use basic SQL Create Table syntax within Google BigQuery to create a table based on columns in 2 existing tables already in BQ.  The [Google SQL dialect reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference) does not show a CREATE. All of the documentation seems to imply that I need to know how to code.

Is there any syntax or way to do a

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ AS 
    SELECT ABC.123, DFG.234 
    from ABC, DFG
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it entirely through a SQL statement.

However, the UI does allow you to save results to a table (max result size is 64MB compressed.  The API and command line clients have the same capabilities.